# customer address attribute's value not visible in customer grid

Tags: magento2, php, customer, address

I Have created some custom address attribute, field is visible in grid and form, but value is not visible in customer grid. (address_email).

I have check customer_grid_flat, for customer attribute it's saving value of custom attribute but for customer address attribute value not saved in the table so, value not visible in customer grid.

I am using Magento 2.2.11 Open-source. is there any patch available?[image: customer grid]

Answer (score 0):

try the below code to create an address attribute and show it in grid and form.

```
 public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {


        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.8') < 0) {

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

 
        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_attribute', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 210,
            'position' => 210,
            'system'=> 0,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'=> 'General Information',
        ]);

        $customAttr = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_attribute');
       
        $customAttr->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                [
                    'customer_address_edit',
                    'adminhtml_customer_address',
                    'customer_register_address'
                ]
            )->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1);

            $customAttr->setData('is_used_in_grid',true);
            $customAttr->setData('is_visible_in_grid',true);
            $customAttr->setData('is_filterable_in_grid',true);
            $customAttr->save();
            
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
```

Comment: I have created this way as well, but attribute value is still not visible in grid after customer save and reindexing